# Can two parameter expansions be combined to a single command in bash?

Tags: bash

I am essentially just replacing a substring with the correct substring, then trimming the "-pod" off of my kubernetes pod names. I reassign them to the same variable. Any way to do this as a one liner?

```
table_name=${pod_name//-/_}
table_name=${table_name::-4}
```

Comment: please update the question to include a) the initial value stored in `table_name` and b) the desired result

Comment: technically speaking ... this is a comparable one-liner: `table_name=${pod_name//-/_}; table_name=${table_name::-4}`; could you update the question with some details on the reason/need for a `'one-liner'`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is limited to _practical_ questions. Taking readable, verbose code and making it less readable in service of excessive terseness is not a practical action; it's the action of a code golfer, and we kicked code golf out to [codegolf.se] almost 15 years ago.

Comment: if the intention is to perform this same pair of operations repeatedly over a large(ish) number of variables you could try a function (that utilizes a nameref) to modify the variables

Comment: Not code golfing, I like to have concise code with well defined variable names. For this purpose I am just looking for something like this:

`# pod_name_example="my-job-pod"
table_name=${(pod_name//-/_)::-4}`

I want the same result table_name="my_job" without having to redefine the table_name variable twice. Purpose being, if I understand what is happening and how I can chain commands like this, then I can start to learn how to write concise, functional, readable bash code.

Unsure why it received such a strong response Charles, regardless it does not matter. The code works as is.